# Computing p-value from numpy.linalg.lstsq output

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, least-squares, p-value

I am using numpy.linalg.lstsq for a very large array, and would like to compute the slope and the significance value (p-value) of the fit. Note, using scipy.stats.linregress() or pearsonr() is not an option, because its computation time is far too slow compared to numpy.linalg.lstsq. I have successfully run numpy.linalg.lstsq and got the slope, and also computed R2, but I do not know how to get the p-value of the slope. Any suggestions? Below is an example of my script

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.random.rand(10,25000000)
A = np.c_[x, np.ones_like(x)]
m,resid,rank,s = np.linalg.lstsq(A, y,rcond=None)
r_square = 1-resid/(x.size*np.var(y,axis=0))
```